# Why is pandas transform on multiple columns slower than running on all individual columns?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm grouping by a single column then transforming multiple data columns. This is suspiciously slow when I do it in a single step. In fact, it's much slower than manually looping through each of the columns to transform and then assembling the results.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

d = {}
n_cats = 400
n_data_cols = 5
cats = 10 * range(n_cats)
d['cat'] = cats
names = []
for i in range(n_data_cols):
    name = 'data{}'.format(i)
    names.append(name)
    d[name] = i * np.arange(len(cats))
df = pd.DataFrame(d)
grp = df.groupby('cat')

print 'all at once'
%timeit _ = grp[names].transform(max)
print 'list comprehension'
%timeit _ = pd.concat([grp[name].transform(max) for name in names], axis=1)
```

produces:

```
all at once
1 loop, best of 3: 159 ms per loop
list comprehension
100 loops, best of 3: 4.9 ms per loop
```

Note that if I decrease `n_cats` and increase `n_reps`, I can get the reverse result. But it doesn't seem like a python loop should ever be faster. Is this not doing what I think it should? The two approaches produce identical numeric outputs.

Comment: I can't reproduce your timings; the all at once method is yielding better performance for me.  What version of pandas as you using?

Comment: all at once
100 loops, best of 3: 5.4 ms per loop --
list comprehension
100 loops, best of 3: 8.88 ms per loop

Comment: I was using 0.18, but just upgraded to 0.20 and now get the same results as you. All at once is now faster. Thanks to whoever fixed this in the last two releases!